# python add multiple arrays together

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, sum

I have multiple 5x5 arrays which are contained within one large array - the overarching shape is: 5 x 5 x 29. I want to sum every 5 x 5 array to produce one single array, instead of 29 single arrays.

I know that you can do something along the lines of:

```py
new_data = data1[:,:,0] + data1[:,:,1] + ... + data1[:,:,29]
```

However, this gets very cumbersome for large arrays. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: This is the very thing loops were designed for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using NumPy, you should be able to do this with:

```
In [13]: data1 = np.arange(100).reshape(5, 5, 4) # For example

In [14]: data1[:,:,0] + data1[:,:,1] + data1[:,:,2] + data1[:,:,3] # Bad way
Out[14]:
array([[  6,  22,  38,  54,  70],
       [ 86, 102, 118, 134, 150],
       [166, 182, 198, 214, 230],
       [246, 262, 278, 294, 310],
       [326, 342, 358, 374, 390]])

In [15]: data1.sum(axis=2) # Good way
Out[15]:
array([[  6,  22,  38,  54,  70],
       [ 86, 102, 118, 134, 150],
       [166, 182, 198, 214, 230],
       [246, 262, 278, 294, 310],
       [326, 342, 358, 374, 390]])
```

Comment: What about for floating point numbers? This only seems to be adding integers.

Comment: @M.Simpson I'm not sure what you mean. This should work regardless of data type. Could you give an example?

Comment: a = [[ 1.5 1.5 1.5] [1.5 1.5 1.5] [1.5 1.5 1.5]]
b = [[ 1.5 1.5 1.5] [1.5 1.5 1.5] [1.5 1.5 1.5]]


both = np.zeros([3,3,2])
both[:,:,0] = a
both[:,:,1] = b


print both.sum(axis=3) 
[[ 2 2 2] [2 2 2] [2 2 2]]


Which works fine. However,
a = [[ 1 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 1]]
b = [[ 1 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 1]]


both = np.zeros([3,3,2])
both[:,:,0] = a
both[:,:,1] = b


print both.sum(axis=3) 
[[ 2 2 2] [2 2 2] [2 2 2]]


When it should be 3's instead of 2's

Comment: @M.Simpson Sorry, it is a little hard to read. Could you update your question or use something like Pastebin instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop. Like this:

```
import numpy as np

new_data = np.zeros((5, 5))
for i in range(29):
    new_data += data1[:,:,i]
```

Comment: This likely won't work because `new_data` is a Python list, and `+=` will just append.

Comment: No, you are still appending to the list. In fact, now you are making unnecessary copies of the list. Anyway, OP is using arrays. Lists and arrays don't mix well.

Comment: What is the definition of `new_data`?

Comment: They likely already have a definition for the array of new_data.

Comment: I am not so sure that is true. It looks like a new variable to me. Anyway, you could make it a 5x5 array of zeroes with `np.zeros` :)

Comment: Wait, I don't understand why it would be `5x5` instead of `5x5x29`?

Comment: The result of the sum has a shape of `(5, 5)`. One dimension is removed during such sum operations.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help! @iz_

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying you have a list of arrays, then use a for loop.

```
for i in range(29):
    new_data+= data1[:,:,i]
```

If you are saying you have a tensor or some ND array you should review and research  numpy's [ND array docs.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)

Comment: What is the definition of `new_data`?